# function in python creating issue

Tags: python

Initially i created a program without a function and has been working fine. however, I have modified program to have good readability and define a function for a process creating issue. not sure where the issue is. only getstreamprogram is creating issue when calling from schemalookup.
previously the logic of getstreamprogram written inside getschema and worked fine

#### Below is the program######

```
def GetStreamName(RepoTableName):
    
  

     # Slicing the parameter file based on it's pattern further in order to match the table name coming from git hub.
    for i in range(len(StreamFileInLines)):
        linessubsplit =StreamFileInLines[i].split("|")
        for eachitem in range(len(linessubsplit)):
            #print("linessubsplit : " +linessubsplit[eachitem])
            if linessubsplit[eachitem] == repotablename and MatchFound == 'N':
                StreamNameFound = linessubsplit
                MatchFound = 'Y'
            elif MatchFound == 'N':
                 StreamNameFound = '  UNK :StreamName do not exist for this table in Param File  '
    return StreamNameFound 
      
                 
                            
def schemalookup(subdirectory ,path) :
    my_non_ods_file = open("U:\Praneet\python\sqlcodeinput\TerdataList_of_table.txt", "r")
    data_non_ods = my_non_ods_file.read().splitlines()

    outputfilename =  'U:\Praneet\python\output_test\\'+str(reponame)+'\\'+str(subdirectory)+'_Referenceto_NonODS_Schemalist.txt'
    ReferencetoNonODSSchemalist = open (outputfilename, "a")
    ReferencetoNonODSSchemalist.truncate(0) # this is required on next run of the program the file is set to empty


   #Reading Paramter file which would be used in the program to find out stream name of a given table name
    #StreamFileOpen = open("U:\Praneet\python\sqlcodeinput\CBMODS.param","r",encoding="latin1")
    #StreamFileInLines = StreamFileOpen.read().split('\n')

  
        
    i=0
   
    foldername = filepath
    try:
            
        for filename in os.listdir (foldername):
            MatchFound = 'N'
            
            if filename.endswith(".sql"):  # checks only file that ends with .sql
                filename_abs_path =  os.path.join(foldername,filename)  # Joins directory name and file name
                print(filename_abs_path)
                repotablename = filename.rsplit(".", maxsplit=2)[0]  # gives the table name from the file name in github.
                print("repotablename : " +str(repotablename))
                GetStreamName(repotablename)
                print("StreamNameFound 2nd: " +str(StreamNameFound))
                         
                 
                

                

                
                #if not os.path.isfile(os.path.join(foldername,filename)):
                 #   continue

                ##### START Parsing inside SQL FIle ####
                
                my_file = open(filename_abs_path, "r",encoding="latin1")   # encode is required as the files in windows may consists unicde format

                i+=1              
                data = my_file.read().split()
                #print(data)
                datastrip =  [x.replace(' ','') for x in data]  # this is to remove any spaces between  schemaname.tablename e.g "PVTECH. abc" will be stripped to "PVTECH.abc" . this is to align data  to reference look up file
                
                for item in data_non_ods:
                    if item in datastrip:  # Checking if word from file exists in the databse list
                        #print("Yes contains the list  "+str(item) +' : ' +str(filename) )
                        ReferencetoNonODSSchemalist.write(str(item) +' , ' +str(filename)+ ', ' +str(StreamNameFound)[1:(len(str(StreamNameFound))-1)]+'\n')
                ##### END Pasing inside SQL FIle ####
            
       
    except:
        print (" Filename" +str(filename) + ' ContainsUnicodeDecodeError')

    print('Total number of files scanned is : '+str(i))
    ReferencetoNonODSSchemalist.close()
   



   


directory = 'U:\Praneet\python\sqlcodeinput\workingdir'
reponame = directory.rsplit('\\',maxsplit=1)[1]
StreamFileOpen = open("U:\Praneet\python\sqlcodeinput\CBMODS.param","r",encoding="latin1")
StreamFileInLines = StreamFileOpen.read().split('\n')

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(directory):
    for subdirectory in dirs:
        filepath = os.path.join(root, subdirectory)
        schemalookup(subdirectory,filepath)
```

Comment: What is the problem? What happens, what should happen? If there are error messages, show them completely as properly formatted text in the question.

Comment: You call on the function `GetStreamName`, but the returned value is just left there, in other words you aren't 'saving' the data. You can assign a variable instead to use the data. This is also why no errors are popping up, because doing that is allowed in python, mostly if a function uses the `print()` function and not the `return` function.

Answer (score 0):

```
GetStreamName(repotablename)
```

You're *calling* the function, but you're not *assigning* the returned result to a variable.

I think you meant to do this:

```
StreamNameFound = GetStreamName(repotablename)
```

Comment: I have tried assigning variable but still get issue at the line where function is being called